# How to wait for an Ajax call working on populating a drop down list in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ok so I have two drop down lists. *List B* populates based on the selection made on *List A* using the Ajax technology.

Now the problem is that once I select an option form *List A*, I am not able to see the *List B* populated as Ajax is taking a lot of time to load. I want to know how to use the Wait condition in this scenario to give Ajax enough time to Load. I am a beginner so I am sorry if my question sounds stupid. But I am really stuck at this for long.

I can't use:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id/xpath)));
```

because the id, `xpath` etc remains the same always, even when the list is not populated.

Comment: <select style="width: 140px;" id="alertcatSelectBox" onchange="populatesubcategory()" class="chpSingleBoxSelect" name="metacatId"><option value="">Select category</option><option  value="93">Item1</option><option value="">Select category</option><option  value="73">Item2</option> <option value="">Select category</option><option  value="90">Item3</option>

Comment: Before selecting option from List A : <select style="width: 180px;" id="alertSubCatSelectBox" onchange="getattributes()" class="chpSingleBoxSelect" name="ghostcitysubcatId"><option value="0">Select sub-category</option></select>

Comment: After selecting option from list A: <select style="width: 180px;" id="alertSubCatSelectBox" onchange="getattributes()" class="chpSingleBoxSelect" name="ghostcitysubcatId"><option value="0">Select sub-category</option><option value="18222216517">Item x</option><option value="18222216518">Item y</option></select>

Comment: I am using Xpath .//*[@id='alertSubCatSelectBox'] but since it does not change before/after selection from List A, its of no use!:(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest two approaches, one is waiting for option `Item x`, the other way is waiting for options count to be greater than one.

So try the followings (untested Java code, so you might need to debug a bit):

Wait for one option you want (either by its value or text):

```java
By byValue = By.cssSelector("#alertSubCatSelectBox > option[value='18222216517']");
//By byText = By.xpath("//select[@id='alertSubCatSelectBox']/option[text()='Item x']");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byValue));
```

Or wait for options count bigger than one

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean hasMoreThanOneOptions(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#alertSubCatSelectBox option")).size() > 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: By.xpath("//select[@id='alertSubCatSelectBox']/option[text()='Item x']"); worked perfectly. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an onchange event call to populatesubcategory fn. This fn shud be doing the second list loading. Can you post the code for that function if available..A wait can be done based on it

Comment: I can't find the code for that function. But I did understand what you said. There is also an onchange function for List B to catch the value, I ll just post the code for that as well. I think it can be of some help.

Comment: <select style="width: 180px;" id="alertSubCatSelectBox" onchange="getattributes()" class="chpSingleBoxSelect" name="ghostcitysubcatId">

Comment: Without fn code you cannot write wait logic on it. Try the logic listed by user1177636

Comment: Also if your appltn uses jquery for ajax then you can try this as well......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208935/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined/17316456#17316456   OR create similar logic if it uses javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void AvoidDropDownDelay(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        wait.Until(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (element.Displayed)
                    return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        });

        var randomOption = new Random();
        wait.Until(d => element.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count > 1);
        const int startOption = 1;
        var endOption = element.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Count;
        var randomNumber = startOption + randomOption.Next(endOption - startOption);
        var select = new SelectElement(element);
        select.SelectByIndex(randomNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery to check for ajax calls that are not complete (C#)

```
        public void WaitForAjaxComplete(int maxSecondsToWait = 20)
        {
        var maxHundrethSeconds = maxSecondsToWait * 10;
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxHundrethSeconds; i++)
        {
            bool isAjaxCompete = false;
            isAjaxCompete = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active == 0");
            if (isAjaxCompete)
            {
                return;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        throw new Exception("Timed out after " + maxHundrethSeconds + " seconds");
        }
```