# Selenium Webdriver to wait until the asyn postback update panel request is completed

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with clickable column header. On first click, the column should get sorted in ascending order and on second click column should get sorted in descending order.
The sorting has been implemented using async postback update-panel (I am not sure how it is done, it is an aspx page).
I would like to automate the sorting functionality using Selenium Webdriver. How can I implement the WAIT condition for the page where page doesn't get reloaded but only the table contents are reloaded. 
**waitForElementPresent** wouldn't work, as no new element is displayed or hid on clicking the header.
PS: Java implentation required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a sample program that is related to a **jquery table**. Below is the flow of execution of the code:

- First, it will navigate to the site.
- Since I am taking the second column "Position" into consideration, it will retrieve first text under the column.
- Then, click on the column header "Position" for sorting in ascending
- Wait, 10 seconds(max),  till the first text changes.
- Print the result accordingly.
- Again, click on the column header "Position" for sorting in descending
- Wait, 10 seconds(max), till the first text changes.
- Print the result accordingly.

  ```
  public class TestSortTable{

    static WebDriver driver;  

    public static void main(String[] args){

      driver = new FirefoxDriver();

      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.get("http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html");

       //For Ascending in column "Position"
       String result = clickAndWaitForChangeText(By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//th[2]"), By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//tr[1]/td[2]"), "Ascending");

       if(result.contains("Fail"))
           System.err.println(result);
       else
           System.out.println(result);

       //For Descending in column "Position"
       result = clickAndWaitForChangeText(By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//th[2]"), By.xpath("//table[@id='example']//tr[1]/td[2]"),"Descending");

       if(result.contains("Fail"))
           System.err.println(result);
       else
           System.out.println(result);

      driver.close();//closing browser instance

  }

  //For clicking on header and waiting till the first text in the column changes
  public static String clickAndWaitForChangeText(By Header_locator, By first_text_locator, String sortorder){

      try{

          String FirstText = driver.findElement(first_text_locator).getText();

          System.out.println("Clicking on the header for sorting in: "+sortorder); //sortorder -> String representing sort order Ascending/Descending

          driver.findElement(Header_locator).click();//Click for ascending/Descending

          //Below code will wait till the First Text changes for ascending/descending
          boolean b = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(first_text_locator, FirstText));

          if(b==true){
              return "Pass: Waiting Ends. Text has changed from '"+FirstText+"' to '"+driver.findElement(first_text_locator).getText()+"'";
          }
          else{
              return "Fail: Waiting Ends. Text hasn't changed from '"+FirstText+"'.";
          } 

      }catch(Throwable e){        
          return "Fail: Error while clicking and waiting for the text to change: "+e.getMessage();
      }

  }
  ```

  }

**NOTE:-** You can use the method ***clickAndWaitForChangeText*** accordingly in your code for the relevant result(s).

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the `JQuery.active` retuns 0. Mine is written in c#. Addition to this, we can also wait for a specific element that you know will satisfy your wait criteria. You can use `fluentWait` or write your [custom wait](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/twist/2.5/help/how_do_i_handle_ajax_in_selenium2.html) to wait until the element exists.

```
 public void WaitForAjax()
    {
          var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
          wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
    }
```

**EDIT:** Java version

```
public void waitForAjaxLoad(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    if((Boolean) executor.executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined")){
        while(!(Boolean) executor.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0")){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Directly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208935/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Can you provide the JAVA code for the above implementation ?

Comment: Yes the implementation is very similar. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208935/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined) for a better and extensive explanation in  `java`